# Equally distributed table columns

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am trying to make simple table with some numerical data. I used package booktabs and overall the table looks very good, but in my opinion it would be better to have columns equally width according to the widest column. Is it possible to make latex automatically stretch these columns equally ?

Thanks for any help.

Table example: 
[image: Example table]
Code:

```latex
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{booktabs}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}[t]{ccccc}
 \toprule
 \# & \textsc{Precision} & \textsc{Recall} & \textsc{F1} &\textsc{MAP} \\
 \midrule
 0 & 0.0117 & 0.6838 & 0.0230 & 0.0112 \\
 1 & 0.0099 & 0.7084 & 0.0195 & 0.0109 \\
 2 & 0.0095 & 0.7096 & 0.0187 & 0.0105 \\
 3 & 0.0088 & 0.7215 & 0.0174 & 0.0101 \\
 4 & 0.0085 & 0.7401 & 0.0168 & 0.0096 \\
 5 & 0.0080 & 0.7467 & 0.0158 & 0.0087 \\
 6 & 0.0079 & 0.7571 & 0.0156 & 0.0088 \\
 7 & 0.0073 & 0.7794 & 0.0145 & 0.0087 \\
 8 & 0.0071 & 0.7902 & 0.0141 & 0.0085 \\
 9 & 0.0069 & 0.7981 & 0.0137 & 0.0084 \\
 10 & 0.0065 & 0.7990 & 0.0129 & 0.0078 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome... \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\extracolsep\fill}ccccc@{\extracolsep\fill}} may helps you ...

Comment: Thank you very much for fast answer, I'll try it.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of the `array` and the `calc` package you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}[t]{c*{4}{w{c}{\widthof{\textsc{Precision}}}}}
 \toprule
 \# & \textsc{Precision} & \textsc{Recall} & \textsc{F1} &\textsc{MAP} \\
 \midrule
 0 & 0.0117 & 0.6838 & 0.0230 & 0.0112 \\
 1 & 0.0099 & 0.7084 & 0.0195 & 0.0109 \\
 2 & 0.0095 & 0.7096 & 0.0187 & 0.0105 \\
 3 & 0.0088 & 0.7215 & 0.0174 & 0.0101 \\
 4 & 0.0085 & 0.7401 & 0.0168 & 0.0096 \\
 5 & 0.0080 & 0.7467 & 0.0158 & 0.0087 \\
 6 & 0.0079 & 0.7571 & 0.0156 & 0.0088 \\
 7 & 0.0073 & 0.7794 & 0.0145 & 0.0087 \\
 8 & 0.0071 & 0.7902 & 0.0141 & 0.0085 \\
 9 & 0.0069 & 0.7981 & 0.0137 & 0.0084 \\
 10 & 0.0065 & 0.7990 & 0.0129 & 0.0078 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for great solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @leandriis suggestions, I suggest the following layout changes:

1. Remove side bearing *i.e*. @{} in table preamble
2. Reduce `\tabcolsep`
3. All letters in heading in `smallcaps`
4. Right align the columns
5. Group the rows by a small space between each fourth row.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5pt}
 \newcommand{\cc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c*{4}{w{r}{\widthof{\textsc{Precision}}}}@{}}
 \toprule
 \# & \cc{Precision} & \cc{Recall} & F1 &\cc{MAP} \\
 \midrule
 0 & 0.0117 & 0.6838 & 0.0230 & 0.0112 \\
 1 & 0.0099 & 0.7084 & 0.0195 & 0.0109 \\
 2 & 0.0095 & 0.7096 & 0.0187 & 0.0105 \\
 3 & 0.0088 & 0.7215 & 0.0174 & 0.0101 \\[0.25\normalbaselineskip]
 4 & 0.0085 & 0.7401 & 0.0168 & 0.0096 \\
 5 & 0.0080 & 0.7467 & 0.0158 & 0.0087 \\
 6 & 0.0079 & 0.7571 & 0.0156 & 0.0088 \\
 7 & 0.0073 & 0.7794 & 0.0145 & 0.0087 \\[0.25\normalbaselineskip]
 8 & 0.0071 & 0.7902 & 0.0141 & 0.0085 \\
 9 & 0.0069 & 0.7981 & 0.0137 & 0.0084 \\
 10 & 0.0065 & 0.7990 & 0.0129 & 0.0078 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image]